# create-react-app crashing with error of not having permission

Tags: node.js, reactjs

When I tried to create a react app I'm having this error. please help me with it.
I tried using administrative permissions and also uninstalling and re-installing nodejs still showing the same error.

```
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\chandan\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...


> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall C:\Users\chandan\my-app\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js

npm ERR! path C:\Users\chandan\my-app\node_modules\nan\package.json
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\chandan\my-app\node_modules\nan\package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\chandan\my-app\node_modules\nan\package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'C:\\Users\\chandan\\my-app\\node_modules\\nan\\package.json\'\n    at Error (native)',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\chandan\\my-app\\node_modules\\nan\\package.json' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\chandan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-09-11T04_28_57_244Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app / from C:\Users\chandan
Done.
```

Answer (score 2):

Clean the cache using following command:

```
npm cache clean -f
```

and then uninstall the create-react-app module and install again and create the new app.

UPDATED:

Install latest version of npm/node and try.

Comment: its not the issue... because I tried it with administrative credentials.

Comment: Install latest version of npm/node and try.

Comment: @Padmika glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, this error is related to anti-virus running in the background. Keep trying, eventually it will work. Or turn off anti-virus, although I personally don't like it - I just keep trying until it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling Windows Antivirus, Dropbox and any other processes that might be locking the folder and/or files.

Also check you npm version (npm -v). I had 5.4.1 and rolled back to 5.3.0:

```
npm install -g npm@5.3.0
```

And it worked!